# .NET Standard add XMLElement Annotation

Tags: c#, .net-standard

This is my first time using `.NET Standard` and I'm confused. All I want to do is add an annotation like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2&viewFallbackFrom=netstandard-1.0/). I need to target `.NET Framework 4.5.2`, so I selected version `1.0`.   The reference is missing, so I need to add the it, but can't find it like I normally would in the not to distant past.

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "CreatedBy")] // No good
public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that you can use `XmlElement` if you're targeting Standard 1.0.  Going by the version [diffs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/standard/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0_diff.md), it looks like it was made available in 2.0.  You might, unfortunately, be out of luck in this case if you need `XmlElement` and target 4.5.2.  Probably would have to make .NET Framework library instead.

If you check out the [.NET Standard version page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) you can click on the different versions of Standard.  Those links take you to the GitHub page for each release so you can see all the APIs that are included in that release along with a diff with the previous version so you can see what's added.

Comment: The links are helpful.  I would expect XmlElement to be part of the System.Xml namespace, but for Standard 1.0 it's not, as you already said.

Comment: You're right, I bumped up the version and the it's available.  Disappointing, but at least I know.

Comment: One thing I might suggest is that if you know you'd be upgrading the .NET version at some point, try to only use what's available in the 2.0 Standard in your Framework library.  That way when you upgrade your .NET version, you could probably also convert the Framework library to a Standard library without too much hassle.